# Counter example to lifting contractibility of a topological space

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I'm looking for a simple example of an open proper continuous map between topological spaces $\varphi:X\to Y$ such that :

- $Y$ is contractible and locally contractible ;
- for any $y\in Y$, $\varphi^{-1}(\{y\})$ is contractible ;
- $X$ is not contractible.

I have an example which is a little bit complicated but I wonder if there exists a simple one.

Comment: What are your examples? (say the complicated one)

Comment: It is a Berkovich space over Banach ring which is not valued field. I'm currently working on this space.

Comment: What about $X = \{(x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1] \;|\; x=0 \;\;\text{or}\;\; (x>0 \;\text{and}\; y=sin(1/x))\}$, $Y=[0,1]$ and $\varphi: X \to Y$ is the projection on the $x$-coordinate? All the conditions are clear except $\varphi$ being open, but I think it is open.

Comment: I may do a mistake but I think this map is not open

Comment: This map is not open because the image of $U=X\cap \{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times[-1,1] |\ |y|<1/2\}$ is an open set but $\varphi(U)$ is not a neighborhood of $0$

Comment: @thibaudlemanissier, Right... my mistake.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084432/submersion-with-contractible-fibers/3087341#3087341

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I knew there were result like for compact CW-complex (using the result of "A Vietoris mapping theorem for homotopy" by S. Smale and the Whitehead theorem). But I didn't knew there was a result without the hypothesis of compactness.